# GAE channels doesn't work after a while

Tags: java, google-app-engine, channel-api

I use channel API in my Java GAE application. It works perfectly fine after I deploy app. I can connect to server and get messages from it in real time. I can even reconnect to new channels when old one expires.

However if I keep my app open for few hours, this user cannot connect to server anymore. I'm getting 404 `/_ah/channel/dev?command=connect&channel=XXX` new Channel opening.

Instance shutdown via admin page doesn't help, however redeploying same code fix issue for another few hours.

Is there are any other solution rather that redeploying app every few hours?

Answer (score 2):

The channel token expires after two hours, see [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/%23Python_Tokens_and_security)

You should create a new token for the same client id and establish a new channel when the error/closed state fires on the client

Comment: Btw I highly recommend an exponential back off on this operation, with a termination state in case a client or server side error causes an epic volume of requests (and hence instances scaling up)

Comment: thank you for you answer. The issue is that reconnection stop working. I did test by setting up channel lifetime to few minutes and verifying that reconnection works very well.

Comment: This is pretty nasty, but try this before (re-)connecting: $("iframe#wcs-iframe").remove(); - I can't find a source for this, but I recall there was an issue of duplicate iframes coming from the gtalk/hangouts chat widget that channels run through. If this works for you'll, I'll update my answer

Comment: Unfortunately, it didn't help. Going even further, when this happens connections are not created even for different user in different browser (tested Chrome -> Safari switch on Mac). However that user can login from different computer and it would work just fine.